# Print data frame with columns center-aligned

Tags: r, printing, dataframe, formatting, center-align

I would like to print a data frame where the columns are center aligned.  Below is what I have I tried, I thought printing the data frame test1 would result in the columns being aligned in the center but this is not the case.  Any thoughts on how I can do this?

```
test=data.frame(x=c(1,2,3),y=c(5,6,7))
names(test)=c('Variable 1','Variable 2')
test[,1]=as.character(test[,1])
test[,2]=as.character(test[,2])
test1=format(test,justify='centre')
print(test,row.names=FALSE,quote=FALSE)
 Variable 1 Variable 2
          1          5
          2          6
          3          7
print(test1,row.names=FALSE,quote=FALSE)
 Variable 1 Variable 2
          1          5
          2          6
          3          7
```

Comment: Do you mean the center of the column?  So 1, 2, 3 line up under the `a` (roughly) in `Variable 1`?

Comment: @TylerRinker Yes that is what I mean.

Comment: @Glen, Does [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12985403/1270695) address your question sufficiently? If not please add a comment so your question can be worked on further.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that in order for this to work as you expect, the "`width`" argument needs to also be specified.

Here's an example:

```
test.1 <- data.frame(Variable.1 = as.character(c(1,2,3)), 
                     Variable.2 = as.character(c(5,6,7)))

# Identify the width of the widest column by column name
name.width <- max(sapply(names(test.1), nchar))
format(test.1, width = name.width, justify = "centre")
#   Variable.1 Variable.2
# 1     1          5     
# 2     2          6     
# 3     3          7
```

But, how does this approach work with columns where the variable names are different lengths? Not so well.

```
test.2 <- data.frame(A.Really.Long.Variable.Name = as.character(c(1,2,3)), 
                     Short.Name = as.character(c(5,6,7)))

name.width <- max(sapply(names(test.2), nchar))
format(test.2, width = name.width, justify = "centre")
#   A.Really.Long.Variable.Name                  Short.Name
# 1              1                           5             
# 2              2                           6             
# 3              3                           7
```

There is, of course, a workaround: change the "width" of each variable name to be equal lengths by padding them with spaces (using `format()`)

```
orig.names <- names(test.2) # in case you want to restore the original names
names(test.2) <- format(names(test.2), width = name.width, justify = "centre")
format(test.2, width = name.width, justify = "centre")
#   A.Really.Long.Variable.Name         Short.Name         
# 1              1                           5             
# 2              2                           6             
# 3              3                           7
```

Comment: and I was going to bust out `sprintf` +1

Comment: Does not seem to work if a column has characters instead of numbers, and they are longer than the column name itself, alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

call this function to get a dataframe to display like that:

```
def pd_centered(df):
    return df.style.set_table_styles([
        {"selector": "th", "props": [("text-align", "center")]},
        {"selector": "td", "props": [("text-align", "center")]}])
```

e.g.:

```
display(pd_centered(original_df))
```

This will center align both the headers and the actual data cells, and you may remove either the `td` or the `th` to disable either one if you like.

Source: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12144